# How to test if a void async function was successful with jest?

Tags: typescript, promise, jestjs, void

How do you concisely test if a void async function executed successfully with jest? I'm using TypeScript.

```
// foo.ts
export class Foo {
  public async bar(): Promise<void> {
    await someAsync();
  }
}
```

How to test that `new Foo().bar()` does not throw an error?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

This is the most semantic way I've found.
It is even just a translation of the test name.

```
describe("Foo.bar()", () => {
      test("Should not throw", async () => {
        await expect(new Foo().bar()).resolves.not.toThrow();
      });
    });
```

Comment: Best answer by far

Comment: For those who, like me, missed it, the `await` is very important. If you omit it then the test will always pass. While I don't have another option to hand, I would prefer an option where that sort of mistake isn't syntactically possible.

Comment: @TobySmith Best solution I've found is a linter that flags unhandled promises (i.e. missing await/void), such as eslint.

Comment: To the future reader: if you try to convert `.rejects.throw` to `.resolves.not.toThrow` then be very careful; the former needs a function and the latter needs a promise. So `await expect(() => Promise.reject()).rejects.toThrow();` and `await expect(Promise.resolve()).resolves.not.toThrow();`

Comment: @TobySmith https://github.com/testing-library/eslint-plugin-testing-library/blob/main/docs/rules/await-async-query.md

Answer (score 22):

The Promise has the advantage that it should not throw at all, rather be resolved or rejected. On the other hand the `toBe()` assertion expects an argument, even though there is a `Promise<void>` in TypeScript.

So what if there is no argument passed (or the argument is void) but it is still evaluated. Then the argument is `undefined`.

```
  test("Should resolve", async () => {
      await expect(new Foo().bar()).resolves.toBeUndefined();
  });
```

Testing for `not.toThrow()` happend to be a false friend for me, because my `Foo.bar()` did not throw, nor was it resolved either.

Comment: You can use .toBeUndefined() matcher to test for undefined

Comment: This seems to be the most up to date answer. My usage: `expect(fs.access(path, mode.R_OK)).resolves.toBeUndefined()`

Comment: ad. "nor was it resolved either" - documentation clearly says `Use resolves to unwrap the value of a fulfilled promise ... If the promise is rejected the assertion fails.` so if your promise from `bar()` was not resolved, it should fail even before it asserts `toThrow()`.
Promise has three states pending, fulfilled and rejected. By using `await` Promise is either fulfilled or rejected. 
Can you please explain, how you end up with unresolved Promise, yet not failed assertion that uses `.resolves.not.toThrow()`?

Comment: [jest 'resolves' doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#resolves),  [mdn Promise doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: It is quite long time ago, and I can not tell whether something was fixed or changed in the meantime. This answer was created by my observation at that point of time. I might come back to that if I proceed work on my project, but no _promises_ (pun intended ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is the best way that I've found. Hoping there's something more elegant.

```
describe("Foo.bar()", () => {
  it("should not throw", async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    try {
      await new Foo().bar();
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    } catch {
      // should not come here
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Also there is no try catch needed (`await` is just enough), as the test would fail anyway if the promise would not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

...alternative is [`resolves`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#resolves) assertion.

```
describe("Foo.bar()", () => {
  it("should not throw", () => {
      return expect(new Foo().bar()).resolves.toEqual();
  });
});
```

Here you have to return result since it's a Promise(and make jest wait until it's fulfilled). It's slightly more laconic if you need just verify resolved(or rejected - there is similar prop `rejects` for checking rejection value).

But in case you need to run several checks after promise-based function is run like

```
describe("Foo.bar()", () => {
  it("should not throw", () => {
      const promise = new Foo().bar()
      expect(promise).resolves.toEqual();
      expect(someMock).toHaveBeenCalled();
      return promise;
  });
});
```

you may find option with `async/await` is more... satisfying?

PS as for you variant

```
describe("Foo.bar()", () => {
  it("should not throw", async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    try {
      await new Foo().bar();
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    } catch {
      // should not come here
    }
  });
});
```

I believe it's not needed to catch an error - so `expect.assertions` also becomes redundant. why?  uncaught exception will fail your test and it's expected no exception so it's fine to fail it. such a structure will be needed if you expect exception and want to check its properties.

Also if test fails option with `expect.assertions` will notify you just about it's failed while uncaught exception will highlight specific statement(useful if test has several  exception-possible statements)

[UPD] also I missed initial point that you need to check if promise is resolved with *any* result(my version check it resolves with `undefined` that is not really good move(it does not ruin anything if function starts returning *something* if it returned *nothing* before). Meanwhile we should have at least one check in test...

So maybe your approach with stub `expect(true)` is the same legit here.

But I'd verify twice if you don't want to make more `expect` in the same test case. is that statement under test really such isolated? or you just explode related checks into separate `it()`?